# how to load css files only for mobile magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Need to load some css files for mobile view  some for desktop view how to load it in magento 2.if mobile view the desktop file need not load .

Comment: 1 way is you can load css files with jquery.
You need to define media query (screen-width) with jquery and load css files according to that.

Comment: Thank you will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to added the media Query into the css file.
So it apply to the particular screen like this.

```
//THIS IS FOR DESKTOP VIEW
.mycustomclass { ..... }

//THIS IS FOR TABLET VIEW
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
   .mycustomclass { ..... }
}

//THIS IS FOR MOBILE VIEW
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
   .mycustomclass { ..... }
}
```